# How to change android studios jdk version (specifically to jdk 8)

Tags: java, android-studio, java-8

I searched a lot on web regarding this question ..but did not find any perfect answer..I am just a begginer so please answer in as simple way as posible

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987228/how-do-i-change-the-intellij-idea-default-jdk#:~:text=Navigate%20to%20%22File%22%20%2D%3E,Default%20Project%20Structure...%22

Comment: Also, note that from AS 4.2 onwards, you cannot run it on Java 8.  You need a Java 11 (or later) installation to run it; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67944752/android-studio-use-java-8-instead-of-11/67944941#67944941